# Multiple openssl on the same application

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, boost, openssl

I have a main openssl version installed in my machine and used by my application.

I have also a shared (.so) library that uses a different version of openssl (imposed by boost 1.76)

I cannot upgrade the operating system openssl.

Is there a way to deal with this without using the LD_PRELOAD variable in Linux?

Comment: You can use `dlopen()`, `dlsym()` etc in runtime.

Comment: Is it possible to link openssl statically in the shared library?

Comment: Do you mean link openssl shared library statically to your app? No, that's not possible. You can create wrapper libraries for different openssl versions and link them to your app.

Comment: I do not use them directly in my code. It's used by boost library.